# Data speed (fps) significantly decreased on USB camera

Tags: usb, signal, communication, cables

I have a 5 meter long inspection camera bought on ebay ([here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5M-6-LED-USB-Waterproof-Endoscope-Borescope-Snake-Inspection-Video-Camera-7mm-HY-/301773329291)), getting 30 fps @ 640x480. I was measuring the resistance between D+ and D- while connected (DP, DM in the actual image), just for fun, during which the buzzer of multimeter beeped. I'm suspecting that i touched the tips of probes to somewhere else and/or shorted D+ and D-.

Then i plugged it in and now i'm getting 4 fps max. at 320x240 resolution. The resistance between D+ and D- now is ~4.4Kohm. I know it's way too high and it's supposed to be 90ohm.

Well since i don't want to break the camera head, i can't replace the shielded USB cable. So is it gone forever or recoverable for instance with a [ferrite bead](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/111423/79136)?[image]

Comment: Sounds like you've broken it in a way such that it's downgraded to USB1.1. At $8 I'd buy a new one and remember the lesson not to play with things that are plugged in. I can't see why you'd think a ferrite would help.

Comment: I thought it might be EMI related. Is it not?

Comment: No, it probably isn't EMI related.

Answer (score 2):

You broke it.  Ditch it, and move on.  Then learn not to go poking at sensitive things, especially with the power on.